# If $\alpha$ is an irrational number, then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ does not have a rational root?

Tags: extension-field, rationality-testing

I'm reading Ross' *"Elementary Analysis"*. He shows the rational zeros theorem and a proof of it. And then there are some examples such as the following ones:

---

> [image]

> [image]

---

The basic idea is that testing all the candidates for rational roots, if none of them is a root, then the number we are testing for irrationality is not rational because as there are no rational roots, then all roots must be irrational or complex.

But I thought about the following: Can't we have a case where we are testing for the irrationality of some $\alpha$ and:

- Some of the candidates for rational roots are roots;
- Some of the candidates for rational roots aren't roots?

I suspect that if $\alpha$ is an irrational number, that is not possible. I recognize the procedure of finding the polynomial $x^6-6x^4 +12x^2-13=0$ given the number $\alpha=\sqrt{2+\sqrt[3]{5}}$ as computing the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. And it seems to me that the case I pointed out can't happen because of something related to field extensions but I can't figure out what is it nor if it is actually true.

---

**The main doubt I have is the truth or falsity of the following proposition:** If $\alpha$ is an irrational number, then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ does not have a rational root. Is this proposition true? If so, why?

Comment: If there were a rational root you would divide by the corresponding linear rational factor and get another rational polynomial of strictly lower degree that has $\alpha$ as a root. Also, having no rational roots is a necessary condition, but not a sufficient one. For example $x^4 - 4$ has no rational roots and it has $\sqrt{2}$ as a root, but it is not the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: However: finding that $a$ is a solution of a certain polynomial (without showing that polynomial is the minimal polynomial), then checking for rational roots of that polynomial, and verifying none of the rational roots is $a$.  This should be easier than showing the polynomial is irreducible.